# form submit to iframe not working - it only refresh the parent and iFrame

Tags: html, iframe, submit

I try to submit a form to an iFrame and get search results within iFrame. Whatever text I write and push search its just refreshing parent and child pages.

I have this parent page code :

```
<form id="SearchForm" <form action="http://itmjobs.ro/" target="my-iframe" method="post">
        <label><strong>What?</strong><em><input type="text" value="job title, keywords or company name"  onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='job title, keywords or company name'" onFocus="if(this.value =='job title, keywords or company name' ) this.value=''" /></em></label>
        <label><strong class="color">Where?</strong><b><input type="text" value="city, state or zip code"  onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='city, state or zip code'" onFocus="if(this.value =='city, state or zip code' ) this.value=''" /></b></label>
        <a href="#" class="SearchForm-link" onClick="document.getElementById('SearchForm').submit()">Search</a>
<div class="wrapper">
    <td><iframe id="my-iframe" iframe name="my-iframe" iframe allowtransparency="yes" align="right" src="http://itmjobs.ro/" frameborder="0" height="1000" scrolling="no" width="1200"></iframe>
```

And this are the fields from iframe code where I need to be submit the text  :

```
<div class="quickSearchInputField">Cuvinte cheie<br/>   <input type="text" value="" class="searchText" name="keywords[all_words]"  id="keywords" />
<div class="quickSearchInputName">Oras<br/><input type="text" name="City[like]"  id="City" class="searchStringLike" value=""  />
<div class="quickSearchInputName"><br/><input type="submit" id="btn-search" class="button" value="Cauta"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return false` on your submission to prevent a page refresh.

```
onClick="document.getElementById('SearchForm').submit() return false;"
```